# Python regex issue, possibly quotes

Tags: python, regex

I have two types of output

```
a)
{'projections': {}, 'band_index': [], 'energy': None, 'kpoint_index': [], 'kpoint': []}
b)
{'band_index': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {<Spin.up: 1>: [9]}), 'kpoint': <pymatgen.electronic_structure.bandstructure.Kpoint object at 0x7f65f2784550>, 'kpoint_index': [28, 29, 188], 'projections': {}, 'energy': 6.5496}
```

and I would like to use

```
import re
cbm=bs.get_cbm()
searchObj=re.search(r '\' +str(energy)+ \' : (.*?) (.*)', cbm, re.M|re.I)
print(searchObj.group(1))
```

where cbm will simply return either a) or b).

I currently get the error

```
searchObj=re.search(r '\' +str(energy)+ \' : (.*?) (.*)', cbm, re.M|re.I)
                                                       ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have very little background in regex, so I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: There is a space between the 'r' and the beginning of your regex pattern.  Remove it to fix the syntx error.

Comment: just do `r"'{}' : (.*?) (.*)".format("energy")`. (plus the space thing!!)

Comment: If I close the space it returns     return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I suspect your `cbm` is not a string but a dictionary. In that case just do `"energy" in cbm`.

Answer (score 0):

`cbm=bs.get_cbm()` returns a `dict` (in both cases), not a `str`.

You cannot (and you don't have to) parse those with a regex!

Case a: it returns a dictionary containing the `"energy"` key.

So to know if you're in case a, just do

```
"energy" in cbm
```

Another way is to use the different value type returned by `'band_index'`:

```
 if isinstance(cbm["band_index"],list):
    # we're in case "a"
    pass
 elif isinstance(cbm["band_index"],dict):  # defaultdict is a dict
    # we're in case "b"
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply Jean-Francois,

I've managed to create this regex which works relatively well for my requirements.

```
cbm=bs.get_cbm() 
searchObj=re.search(r"energy\':\s(.*)", str(cbm),re.I) 
print(searchObj.group())
```